# php html text after space not showing in title attribute for <a>

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a link `<td><a href="task_id=<?php echo $rs['task_id'];?> 
title =<?php echo $rs['task_description'] > <?php echo $rs['task_log_name'] </a> </td>`

Here I want the description to come as tooltip. But the text from the database breaks after the first space. If the description is "Team cannot do this task today" Only "Team" is shown in the tooltip. The rest is lost.

Can anybody help? I am using PHP/mySQL

Thanks in advance

Pre

Comment: code are not valid, use some IDE - NetBeans, Komodo Edit, PhpStorm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Inspect your output** (e.g., just "view source") and find that the value of the `title` attribute is not quoted (and the quote from `href` is never closed):

```
<td><a href="task_id=N title =Team cannot do this task today > task_log_name </a> </td>
```

Do this:

```
<td><a href="task_id=<?php echo $rs['task_id'];?>" title="<?php echo $rs['task_description']"> <?php echo $rs['task_log_name']; ?> </a> </td>
```

To get:

```
<td><a href="task_id=N" title="Team cannot do this task today"> task_log_name </a> </td>
```

Comment: Thanks, the missing quotes in title tag was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put title value in `"quotes"`.

```
<td><a href="task_id=<?php echo $rs['task_id'];?>" title ="<?php echo $rs['task_description']; ?>" > <?php echo $rs['task_log_name']; ?> </a> </td>
```

Besides, you're missing PHP closing tags there.